# How to change the thickness of the box frame in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia

I am using the following Julia code.

```
using Plots

x = 1:10
y = rand(10)

plot(x, y, framestyle = :box)
```

How to increase the thickness of the box frame?

Comment: As [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/4261) is still open, I'd wager it's not possible. At least not with the GR backend

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `thickness_scaling`, but this requires a proportional correction by the same scale factor of the other plot elements.

For example:

```
using Plots

x = 1:10
y = rand(10)
sf = 2    # scale factor
plot(x, y, framestyle=:box, thickness_scaling=sf, linewidth=1/sf, tickfontsize=10/sf)
```